# Add Reference to Model in Ruby with Column_Name different from Model_Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake

I have a `User` model in my application and I'm also creating another object that belongs to a user, lets call it `myObject`... Now, myObject has one relation to the user that created it and one relation to many users for something else.

How can I have a property in myObject that has a `belongs_to` relationship with users and is called `created_by`?

How can I have a property in myObject that has a `has_many` relationship with users and is called `members`?

Answer (score 0):

It would look more or less like

```
User
has_many :memberships
has_many :ownedgroups, :class_name => "Group"
has_many :groups, :through => memberships

Membership
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :groups

Group
has_many :memberships
belongs_to :owner, class_name => "User"
has_many :users, :through => memberships
```

I would recommend reading [Active Record Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) specially their many-to-many parts.